# How do I insert a line in a .csv file into a Person[] people object

Tags: java, arrays

So I have a Person class and a biostats.csv file that I want to import into a person[] array. How can I do this? I want to make it so that each line is one line, so one Person object array would be Alex and his details, the second Person object array would be Bert and his details etc etc...
Thank you in advance

```
public Person() {}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public double getHeight() {
    return height;
}
public void setHeight(double height) {
    this.height = height;
}
public double getWeight() {
    return weight;
}
public void setWeight(double weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}
public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}
```

This is what I have but I think it's completely wrong

```
public static void buildFromFile(String location) throws FileNotFoundException{

    File file = new File(location);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

    while(input.hasNextLine()) {
        String data = input.nextLine();
        for(int i = 0; i <= people.length; i++) {
            people[i].setName(data);
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= people.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(people[i]);
    }
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gnc60.png here's a link to the file

Comment: Show what you have tried

Comment: Define "wrong". What doesn't work? Please have a look around and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). In particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Always quote the exact error, rather than just saying you get an error.

Comment: @livelive96 that's an image. Post the csv in textual form in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The class [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) provides line oriented functions.

The entire round cycle would look like:

```
Path path = Paths.get(location);
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path); // Load all from file.

List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
for (String line : lines) {
    ...
    persons.add(person);
}


List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
for (Person person : persons) {
    ...
    lines.add(line);
}

Files.write(path, lines); // Store all to file.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [apache commons csv](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) you could do something like this:

```
public static Person[] buildFromFile(File file) throws IOException {
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
    try (InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
            Reader in = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8")) {
        CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withDelimiter(';');
        Iterable<CSVRecord> records = format.parse(in);
        for (CSVRecord record: records) {
            persons.add(recordToPerson(record));
        }
    }
    return persons.toArray(new Person[persons.size()]);
}

private static Person recordToPerson(CSVRecord record) {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setName(record.get(0));
    person.setGender(record.get(1));
    person.setAge(Integer.parseInt(record.get(2)));
    person.setHeight(Double.parseDouble(record.get(3)));
    person.setWeight(Double.parseDouble(record.get(4)));
    return person;
}
```